# d3.js. How to append documentFragment to SVG?

Tags: d3.js, svg, documentfragment

See my example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zeleniy/5g6u33wy/1/). One red `rect` exists as static markdown. Second green `rect` is appended using [append](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#append) method. Where is blue `rect`? You can see with any document inspector that blue `rect` already inserted within `svg` element, but it is not visible. Why? I try to insert big amount of rectangles into SVG using `documentFragment` but they all are not visible...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you have to help d3 by telling it the rect is an [svg rect](http://jsfiddle.net/5g6u33wy/2/) and not some mythical html rect element. E.g.

```
var svg = d3.select("svg");
svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 50)
    .attr("height", 50)
    .attr("x", 50)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("fill", "green")
var documentFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
d3.select(documentFragment).append("svg:rect")
    .attr("width", 50)
    .attr("height", 50)
    .attr("x", 100)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("fill", "blue")
console.log(documentFragment);
svg.node().appendChild(documentFragment);
```

Not sure but this may be a bug in d3.

Comment: Wow, super! It works. But what means colon in `svg:rect`?

Comment: It means explicitly that the rect should be created in the SVG namespace, rather than d3 figuring it out for itself.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Robert Longson i did working example [on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zeleniy/5g6u33wy/):

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 50)
    .attr("height", 50)
    .attr("x", 50)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("fill", "green")
var documentFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
d3.select(documentFragment).append("svg:rect")
    .attr("width", 50)
    .attr("height", 50)
    .attr("x", 100)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("fill", "blue")
svg.node().appendChild(documentFragment);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="400px" height="400px">
    <rect width="50" height="50" x="0" y="0" fill="red"></rect>
</svg>
```